# Which job title (entry-level) for PMO member?

Tags: project-management-style, roles, pmo

I am looking for possible job titles for PMO employees (entry-level).

Our PMO has a leading Manager PMO (once called Project Management Officer) who has a strategic focus, and now we are looking for a good job title for junior positions which should support the manager in project documentation, communication, and analysis.

I only found titles in PM theory articles like "project assistant" or "junior project manager" which are not convenient as the person should not work IN projects but just at the meta-level having the task to prepare reporting, communications, meetings, GANTT charts, etc. with the information extracted by the project managers.

What job title can fit this description?

Answer (score 1):

How about **Project Coordinator**?

Comment: This title is seen at our company as someone who has the power to make decisions. That's why, unfortunately, we cannot use it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

How about [**Project Expediter**](https://pmstudycircle.com/2015/11/project-expediter-vs-project-coordinator/)?

The [PMBOK 5th Ed](https://www.amazon.com//dp/1935589679/), has this to say about the role:

> A project expediter works as staff assistant and communications coordinator. The expediter cannot personally make or enforce decisions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is indeed a really interesting title we never had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

How about calling the role PMO Secretary?

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately, we have the "homework" from HR/management to not name them assistant or secretary to not demotivate them (I don't understand it but they have this trend going on) -.- (makes things so complicated)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the term "PMO Analyst" being used for junior PMO personnel. How do other departments / units within your organisation refer to similar positions - say in finance or Personnel areas? Could you align with them in some way?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In other departments, they simply refer to them as "assistants". Unfortunately, the HR department wants to stop using "assistant" titles (don't ask me why, it is said they seem to have the impression that employees called assistants feels discriminated). That's why we struggle now to find an alternative matching the tasks.